# How do I stop command-f from sharing state across applications on Mac OS X (10.8.2)?

Tags: mac, find-and-replace

If I have a find bar (command-f) open in two applications, and I change the text in one, the text in the other changes to match as soon as I tab over to the second application. Is there a way to turn this off so that the find bar is only populated by things I type into it?

For example:

```
1. Command-f in Sublime Text for "variable_name"
2. Command-f in Chrome for "some_type"
3. Tab back to Sublime
4. Find bar in Sublime now says "some_type" 
     (and Sublime auto-scrolls to the next mention of some_type)
```

Comment: It is usually called something like the find pasteboard or shared find clipboard, and there is an NSFindPboard constant for it in the NSPasteBoard class. There is a [similar question at Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/78894/is-there-any-way-to-disable-mac-os-x-global-search-string-propagation), but it doesn't have any solutions at the moment.

Comment: Thanks. More googling digs up [this post](http://web.archiveorange.com/archive/v/JT06FEyA9JaZVCSOzcGa) that suggests it's impossible to disable.